# No route matches [DELETE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ребята опытные, подскажите, как решить проблему: есть ссылка на удаление ответа, вложенного в вопрос:

```
link_to 'delete', questions_answers_path(@question, answer), method: :delete
```

При нажатии вываливается ошибка роутинга:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/questions/1434/answers.121"
```

Ресурсы вложенные:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers , shallow: true
end
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А можно вывод из `rake routes` посмотреть?

Comment: наверное лучше ссылку на гист: https://gist.github.com/Navarrskij/1a5422a37760eb296b0e18467cc15393

Comment: Ссылка плоха тем, что в один день она может стать недоступна. На SO за это сильно ругают (иногда).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращайтесь напрямую к `answer_path`, передавая id ответа:

```
link_to 'delete', answer_path(answer), method: :delete
```

Где `answer` -- id ответа